# Finding all permutations of given string and storing them in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, permutation

I am new to C++ and am trying to learn the syntax better. I have created a function that finds all possible permutations of a given string and stores them in a linked list. The linked list is returned at the end of the function. So far what I have goes to the point where the length of the word is 1 then seg faults. I believe it is seg faulting before it enters the if conditional but I am unsure why.

Note: I am trying to do this function iteratively, I realize recursively would be much easier.

```
List :: List()
{
    head = NULL;
}

Node :: Node()
{
    word = "";
    next = NULL;
}

List allAnagrams(string input_str)
{

    int length = input_str.length();
    List *list = new List();
    Node *new_head = new Node;
    new_head->word = input_str;
    list->head = new_head;
    Node *curr = new Node;
    curr = new_head;

    std::sort(input_str.begin(), input_str.end());
    
    if (length == 0) {
        return *list;
    }
    
    do {
        cout << "\n" + input_str;
        curr = curr->next;
        curr->word = input_str;

    }
    while(std::next_permutation(input_str.begin(), input_str.end()));
    return *list;
}
```

Comment: Use std::string, and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation to enumerate over all permutations. Then use std::list<string> instead of writing your own. The whole idea is that C++ has a standard library you should check first, you will have less bugs and you can focus more on what you want to do. For sorting you can then use [sort for lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort). Though probably it is more efficient just to use std::vector<std::string> and use std::sort on that. Try to avoid doing too much with new/delete when you are just starting out.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Thank you I didn't know there was a permutation function in C++ already. However, I have added that into my code and I am still getting a segmentation fault error. I believe it has to do with the way I am loading the words into my linked list.

Comment: Yeah datastructures can be a pain to get right. Specially when you use manual new/delete and forget to initialize variables (to nullptr) explicitly. Try to refactor your code so that you List class is the one managing the nodes, that should not be done by the `allAnagrams` function. That way you can test your list seperatly before you use it, a debugger will really help you too I think. Summary : In your while loop I would expect to see something like list.add(input_str); instead of explicit node managment code.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your solution is by far too complicated.

For example: Do not create a `new` list in your function and return the derefenced value. This will lead to problems.

Then I do not understand your whole logic for adding new nodes to a list.

In the below example, I show you 2 different but a very simple solutions, to add the next new word always to the front of the list (which will give you a somehow reversed list), and the standard implementation by adding new nodes at the end of the list. Here a special handling for the empty list is neeeded.

Additionally, if you allocate memory with `new`, you must release it with `delete`.

But in this case the recommendation would be to use either smart pointers or even better, use a `std::list` in the first place.

Anyway, please see the below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

// A rudimentary node for demo purposes
struct Node {
    std::string word{};
    Node *next{};
};
// A rudimentary list for demo purposes 
struct List{
    Node* head{};
};
// Create all anagrams and add to front of list
List allAnagrams1(std::string& str) {
    
    // Define the list, which we will return
    List list{};
    
    // If the input string is empty, we will do nothing
    if (not str.empty()) {
        
        // Necessary for calculating the permutation
        std::sort(str.begin(),str.end());
        
        // Do for all permutations of the word
        do{
            // Create a new node for the next permutation
            Node *nextWord = new Node{str,list.head};
            // Replace head by this
            list.head = nextWord;

        }  while(std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
    }
    return list;
}
// Create all anagrams and add to end of list
List allAnagrams2(std::string& str) {
    
    // Define the list, which we will return
    List list{};
    
    // If the input string is empty, we will do nothing
    if (not str.empty()) {
        
        // Necessary for calculating the permutation
        std::sort(str.begin(),str.end());
        
        // Do for all permutations of the word
        do{

            // Create a new node for the next permutation
            Node *nextWord = new Node{str,nullptr};

            // If the list is empty
            if (list.head == nullptr) {
                // EMpty list. The just vreated node will be the new head
                list.head = nextWord;
            }
            else {
                // List was not empty, find last element of list
                Node* iter = list.head;
                while (iter and iter->next)
                    iter = iter->next;
                // Last element found. Add new node
                iter->next = nextWord;
            }

        }  while(std::next_permutation(str.begin(), str.end()));
    }
    return list;
}


int main()
{
    // Test string
    std::string s{"Hello"};
    // Get all permutations
    List list = allAnagrams2(s) ;
    
    // Now show all elements in the list
    Node *node = list.head;
    while (node) {
        std::cout << node->word << '\n';
        node = node->next;
    }
    
    // Release memory
   node = list.head; 
    while (node) {
        // Store the next node pointer into a temporary
        Node *temp = node->next;
        // Release memory and delete the node
        delete node;
        // Set the node* to next
        node = temp;
    }
}
```

.

.

---

.

.

And as a bonus, please see an example of a Singly Linked List

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

// Very simple implementation of a forward list
template <class T>
class SinglyLinkedList {

    // The node
    struct Node {
        T data{};     // Data. Would normally be a templated argument
        Node* next{};   // And the pointer to the next node

        Node(const T& i, Node* n = nullptr) : data(i), next(n) {}; // Simple constructor to set a value and next pointer
    };

    Node* head{};       // This is the start of the list
    // It would be advisable to have a tail pointer. We use the more inefficient approach here
    Node* getLast() const { Node* n{ head }; while (n and n->next) n = n->next; return n; }

public:
    // Constructor / Destructor --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ~SinglyLinkedList() { clear(); }

    // Default constuctor
    SinglyLinkedList() {}   // Default
    // From an initialization list
    SinglyLinkedList(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) { clear();  for (const T& i : il) push_back(i); } // From initializer list
    // Copy constructor
    SinglyLinkedList(const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move constructor. Will steal the elements from the other 
    SinglyLinkedList(SinglyLinkedList&& other) noexcept { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }
    // Assignment operator
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (const SinglyLinkedList& other) { clear(); for (const T& i : other) push_back(i); }
    // Move assignment operator 
    SinglyLinkedList& operator = (SinglyLinkedList&& other) { head = other.head; other.head = nullptr; }

    // Housekeeping --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void clear() { Node* tmp{ head }; while (tmp) { Node* toDelete{ tmp }; tmp = tmp->next; delete toDelete; } head = nullptr; }
    int empty() const { return head == nullptr; }
    int size() const { int k{}; Node* n{ head }; while (n) { ++k; n = n->next; } return k; }

    // Modify content --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    void push_back(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); Node* l = getLast(); if (l) l->next = n; else head = n; }
    void push_front(const T& i) { Node* n = new Node(i); n->next = head; head = n; };
    void pop_back() { // This is a little bit more difficult in a singly linked list
        if (head) {
            Node* n{ head }, * previous{};
            while (n and n->next) {
                previous = n;
                n = n->next;
            }
            delete n;
            if (previous)
                previous->next = nullptr;
            else
                head->next = nullptr;
        }
    }
    void pop_front() { if (head) { Node* tmp = head->next; delete head; head = tmp; } }

    // Access elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    T back() const { Node* n = getLast(); return n ? n->data : 0; }
    T front() const { return head ? head->data : 0; };

    // Add iterator properties to class ---------------------------------------------------------------
    struct iterator {                           // Local class for iterator
        Node* iter{};                           // Iterator is basically a pointer to the node
        Node* head{};

        // Define alias names necessary for the iterator functionality
        using iterator_category = std::bidirectional_iterator_tag;
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = T;
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;

        // Constructor
        iterator() {}
        iterator(Node* n, Node* h) : iter(n), head(h) {}

        // Dereferencing
        reference operator *() const { return iter->data; }
        pointer operator ->() const { return &iter->data; }

        // Aithmetic operations
        iterator& operator ++() { if (iter) iter = iter->next; return *this; }
        iterator& operator --() { Node* tmp = head; while (tmp and tmp->next != this->iter) tmp = tmp->next; iter = tmp;  return *this; }
        iterator operator ++(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; ++* this; return temp; }
        iterator operator --(int) { iterator temp{ *this }; --* this; return temp; }

        iterator operator +(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++temp; else while (k++)--temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator +=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)++* this; else while (k++)--* this; return *this; };
        iterator operator -(const difference_type& n) const {
            iterator temp{ *this };  difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--temp; else while (k++)++temp; return temp; }
        iterator operator -=(const difference_type& n) {
            difference_type k{ n }; if (k > 0) while (k--)--* this; else while (k++)++* this; return *this; };

        // Comparison
        bool operator != (const iterator& other) const { return iter != other.iter; }
        bool operator == (const iterator& other) const { return iter == other.iter; }
        bool operator < (const iterator& other) const { return iter < other.iter; }
        bool operator <= (const iterator& other) const { return iter <= other.iter; }
        bool operator > (const iterator& other) const { return iter > other.iter; }
        bool operator >= (const iterator& other) const { return iter >= other.iter; }

        // Difference. Also complicated, because no random access
        difference_type operator-(const iterator& other) const {
            difference_type result{};
            Node* n{ iter };
            while (n and n != other.iter) {
                ++result;
                n = n->next;
            }
            return result;
        }
    };

    // Begin and end function to initialize an iterator
    iterator begin() const { return iterator(head, head); }
    iterator end() const { return iterator(nullptr, head); }

    // Functions typcical for forward lists ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Easy, becuase we can operate form the current iterator and do not need the "previous" element
    iterator insertAfter(iterator& pos, const T& i) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* n = new Node(i, pos.iter->next);
            pos.iter->next = n;
            result.iter = n;
        }
        return result;
    }
    iterator eraseAfter(iterator& pos) {
        iterator result(nullptr, head);
        if (pos.iter and pos.iter->next) {
            Node* tmp = pos.iter->next->next;
```